# Create many plots at once based on some conditions

Tags: r

I have a big table with two columns as in the exemple I created below. It covers the data from 5 time series. I need to create for top_3 TS the spectrum with a predefined R function and to have these three spectrums printed either in different plots (at once) or in the same one to compare them visualy.
This is an exemple I created and the way I started to solve this out.

```
set.seed(123)
library(gridExtra)
category = rep(c("TS1", "TS2", "TS3", "TS4","TS5"), times=5)
dt <- data.table(category , items = sample(1:1000, 25, TRUE) )  

top_TS <- unique(dt[ , .(category, items)], by = "category")
top_TS <- top_cat[order(-items)][1:3, ]
#top_cat$items<- as.character(top_cat$items)
```

My partial solution

```
    dt4 <- dt %>%
       filter(category == "TS4")
       sp4 = spectrum(dt4,  log = "no") 
    dt2 <- dt %>%
      filter(category == "TS2")
      sp2 = spectrum(dt2,  log = "no") 
   dt1 <- dt %>%
      filter(category == "TS1")
      sp1 = spectrum(dt1,  log = "no")
```

#plots?

Any thought on how I can make it properly (function like)?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```r
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
dt4 <- dt %>%
  filter(category == "TS4")
sp4 = spectrum(dt4,  log = "no") 
dt2 <- dt %>%
  filter(category == "TS2")
sp2 = spectrum(dt2,  log = "no") 
dt1 <- dt %>%
  filter(category == "TS1")
sp1 = spectrum(dt1,  log = "no") 
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

To have three plots on the same page, or:

```r
dt4 <- dt %>%
  filter(category == "TS4")
sp4 = spectrum(dt4,  log = "no") 
dt2 <- dt %>%
  filter(category == "TS2")
sp2 = spectrum(dt2,  log = "no", add = TRUE) 
dt1 <- dt %>%
  filter(category == "TS1")
sp1 = spectrum(dt1,  log = "no", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

To have all three lines on one plot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . It solve the problem only partialy as my real data contains around 50 time series and  I would like to get rid of the combersome part with explicitely manually define each time series as I did in the exemple above dt4, dt2,dt1, etc. This is the part I need to automate it too . Therefore I thought, I would need a function maybe.

Comment: @gogo88 I see. You are going to have difficulties trying to plot 50 lines on a single page though.